# Application on Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook

As you probably know, Facebook has changed the layout again for Page (Aka Fan Page)

If I develop an application for facebook page, is it possible to display the canvas/data on the sidesbars (Left or right) instead of main content/canvas page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you can't you have to "Stick" with the frame Facebook gives you and alter your design to fit within the new structure (e.g. using horizontal tabs instead of sidebars)